# How to use correctly the og meta tags for sharing GIFs on facebook

Tags: html, facebook, gif, meta-tags, facebook-share

I am trying to share my [link](http://crazygifs.net/gif/216) page in facebook in order to generate a GIF (with the rounded GIF symbol) using the `og` meta tags:

```
            <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
            <meta property="og:url" content="https://i.giphy.com/YuXbch37iz5ao.gif" />
            <meta content="video.other" property="og:type" />
            <meta property="og:image" content="https://i.giphy.com/YuXbch37iz5ao.gif" />
            <meta content="image/gif" property="og:image:type" />
            <meta property="og:image:width" content="384" />
            <meta property="og:image:height" content="480" />
            <meta content="991618354275198" property="fb:app_id" />
            <meta content="crazygifs" property="og:site_name" />
```

And the result is it after sharing the link in facebook:

[image: result]

And the expected result should be the  image above with this the GIF symbol:

[image: GIF symbol]

It happens with some gifs, if I try to do the same thing with this [link](http://crazygifs.net/gif/213), it works.

Comment: Hello. Have you figured it out? I'm trying the same, but it makes no sense. It just sometimes works, and others not. I have been seeing this happening even to giphy

Comment: no, and facebook developers helps doesn't help...

Comment: I have similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72976121/why-facebook-does-not-animate-gif-if-gif-is-used-as-ogimg

Answer (score -1):

I assume that is a rendering problem from facebook. No solution so far...